# Making tabs appear smaller in vim

Tags: vim, tabs, whitespace, spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab key == 4 spaces and auto-indent after curly braces in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234564/tab-key-4-spaces-and-auto-indent-after-curly-braces-in-vim)
>   [Vim: how to redefine tab as 4 spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/vim-how-to-redefine-tab-as-4-spaces)

I'm writing in vim, and I'm on the tabs side of the tabs vs. spaces war.

However, the tabs are taking up quite a bit of screen space. How can I make it so that they are functionally identical to tabs, but display the same length as, say, four spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh my, [the google-fu is not strong in this one...](https://www.google.nl/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=vim+set+tab+to+4+spaces&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: Note that any special line-to-line formatting (e.g. indented line contiunations) will look vastly different in anyone else's editor with different (e.g. default tab=8 spaces) settings.

Comment: @Wrikken Those certainly looked at the time like they were saying "convert all of the tab characters into 4 space characters". I didn't want to convert them to 4 space characters, so I specified, which I haven't found a site on the internet that specifies the difference aside from this page (not that I'm not sure it exists)

Comment: In Vim, "size of tab characters" and "how many spaces to insert per indent level" are distinct question.  Here's a better question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054627/how-do-i-change-tab-size-in-gvim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add

```
set tabstop=4
```

to your $HOME/.vimrc