# How to I reduce the indentation in my Mac terminal shell?

Tags: vim, indentation, vi

I have started using vi in the terminal to write shell scripts. However,  I noticed that the indentation is very large. In the preference panel, where could I change the indentation?

Comment: I've updated the tags. This is not a shell issue; it's controlled by your editor. I presume you're using the `vim` implementation of `vi`; please update the tags if you're not (type `:version` in your editor to verify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using vi, you have to set the tab size using vi options.

when you first open the file, type : then enter

```
set ts=4
```

and this will set the tab spacing to 4 spaces per tab.

Comment: Both `tabstop` (`ts`) and `shiftwidth` (`sw`) are likely to be relevant. See the accepted answer to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054627/how-do-i-change-tab-size-in-vim).

Answer (score 0):

The OS X Terminal doesn't support changing the indentation size. You have to change the settings in vi.