# How to insert tab character when expandtab option is on in Vim

Tags: vim

When I'm in insert mode and I have the [`expandtab`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27) option switched on, pressing <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> results in inserting the configured number of spaces.

But occasionally I want to insert an actual tab character.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 567, accepted):

You can use `<CTRL-V><Tab>` in "insert mode". In insert mode, `<CTRL-V>` inserts a literal copy of your next character.

If you need to do this often, @Dee`Kej suggested (in the comments) setting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert a real tab with this mapping:

```
:inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V><Tab>
```

Also, as noted by @feedbackloop, on Windows you may need to press `<CTRL-Q>` rather than `<CTRL-V>`.

Comment: And then use `.` to repeat the last command if you want to insert multiple tabs.

Comment: I had some problems using this combination because I was in Command mode. Make sure you execute this command in EDIT mode.

Comment: Note: If you're using gVim on Windows, you'll likely need to use `CTRL` + `Q` instead - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951672/how-can-i-insert-a-real-tab-character-in-vim

Comment: What if I got <CTRL-V> mapped?

Comment: If you've mapped <CTRL-V>, you should really unmap it. Otherwise you're going to need to use horrid hacks for entering non-standard characters (Unicode etc, not just tabs). One hack that kind of works is `imap xx <Esc>:let @a="\t"<CR>"api` which will allow you to type `xx` and have it expand to a real tab. (Note that `imap xx <Tab>` will not work as the tab will get expanded).

Comment: I've just my a simple shortcut for this case and it seems to be working (not breaking anything else): `inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V><Tab>` -- You can put it in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: @Dee'Kej yep that seems sane, and worthwhile if you often need to insert real tabs. I'm going to add it to the body so its up there for everyone to see.

Comment: @Dee'Kej your key mapping doesn't seem to work for me. Pressing Shift+Tab doesn't do anything. Maybe it has to do with vim not sending the Shift+Tab key combo?

Comment: @TriNguyen Its likely that your OS is using Shift+Tab for something else, and vim is never seeing it. You may be able to disable this key binding when vim is active, or just choose something your OS is not using.

Comment: I have `set expandtab` in my `~/.vimrc`, so in Insert mode the `<Ctrl-v><tab>` keypress inserts spaces when `<tab>` is pressed. Adding `inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V><Tab>` to my `~/.vimrc` allows me to insert tabs in Insert mode, using the "Shift-tab" keypress.

Comment: @VictoriaStuart I also use `expandtab` - but for me `<C-V><Tab>` works just fine without any need for a fix. What vim version are you using? Maybe something has changed between versions? Or maybe somethng else you've got installed is interfering?

Comment: Neovim (NVIM v0.2.2) but my ~/.vimrc is huge, so that is likely the difference.

Answer (score 42):

You can disable expandtab option from within Vim as below:

```
:set expandtab!
```

or

```
:set noet
```

**PS:** And set it back when you are done with inserting tab, with "set expandtab" or "set et"

**PS:** If you have tab set equivalent to 4 spaces in .vimrc (softtabstop), you may also like to set it to 8 spaces in order to be able to insert a tab by pressing tab key once instead of twice (set softtabstop=8).

Comment: In short: `set et` and `set noet` to switch `tab` and `space` as need.

Comment: Ctrl+V caused paste to happen and I did not have time to adjust keybindings. This helped

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [`expandtab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27):

> To insert a real tab when [`expandtab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27) is on, use [`CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)`<Tab>`. See also [`:retab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab) and [ins-expandtab](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#ins-expandtab).
>   This option is reset when the [`paste`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27)
>   option is set and restored when the [`paste`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) option is reset.

So if you have a mapping for toggling the `paste` option, e.g.

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

you could also do `<F2>Tab<F2>`.