# How can I insert a real tab character in Vim?

Tags: vim, configuration, supertab

When I have my vimrc here:

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set smarttab
```

And I have supertab plugin installed. Whenever I am in insert mode I press tab, it shows the auto completion, but sometimes I would like to insert a real tab character in a string literal like. So what I mean whenever I press tab in double quotes string literal, it should input we a real tab character.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

While in insert mode or command mode (the `:` prompt at the bottom of the editor), type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> signals Vim that it should take the next character literally. Even in insert mode.

UPDATE:

As noted by Herbert Sitz, if gVim is in Windows mode (default), you must use <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in place of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: That's it, but on Windows if Win compatibility is set on in vimrc (which is the default) you need to do `CTRL` + `Q` then `TAB`.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: Good point. I forgot all about Windows mode for gVim. I'll note that as well.

Comment: CTRL+Q simply puts me into visual block mode so a subsequent TAB does nothing. Am I missing something here? Something wrong with my configuration maybe?

Comment: @BenFranklin You have to be in last line mode (the command prompt with : at the bottom of the screen) or in insert mode for CTRL+V (or Q) to take the next character literally. When you are in the default command mode, it will put you in block mode as you have noted.

Answer (score 8):

@Samnang: I have a similar setup as you; unfortunately, Jason's answer did not work, for me.

This is a workaround:

- Substitute some character (e.g. a backtick: `) or characters (e.g. a unique alphanumeric string: zzz) where you want your tab(s)
- Select the text (Visual mode) and do a search/replace,

  ```
  :'s/`/\t/g
  ```

---

Updated answer, inspired by @Cyryl1972 's comment.

To insert a tab at beginning of all lines (note also: no need to select lines, for any of the following code, as that's included in the line matching part of the expression):

```
:1,$s/^/\t\1/
```

Insert tab after first 10 characters in all lines:

```
:1,$s/^\(.\{10}\)/\1\t/
```

Explanation - first part:

```
:1,$      Match from line 1 to end of file
^(.{10}   Collect (preserve) all text from beginning of line to position 10
          (you need to escape the parentheses, \( and \), as well the FIRST
          (left) curly brace, only: \{ -- as it, { , appears to have special
          meaning in regex when used for this purpose
```

Explanation - second part:

```
/1        Add back the preserved text
\t        Insert a tab
```

... and the rest of the line is automatically restored, as well.

Current line, only:

```
:s/^/\t\1/
```

Example:  insert tab at position 10 (0-indexed) at lines 2-4:

```
1234567890abcdefghij 
1234567890abcdefghij 
1234567890abcdefghij 
1234567890abcdefghij 
1234567890abcdefghij 

:2,4s/^\(.\{10}\)/\1\t/

1234567890abcdefghij 
1234567890  abcdefghij 
1234567890  abcdefghij 
1234567890  abcdefghij 
1234567890abcdefghij
```

References (StackOverflow):

- [Replace character in specific position with another character using regular expression, Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769148/replace-character-in-specific-position-with-another-character-using-regular-expr)
- [How do I add a character at a specific position in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841350/how-do-i-add-a-character-at-a-specific-postion-in-a-string)

References (other):

- [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: the solution works too: :1,$s/^\(.\)/\t\1/ (insert a tabulation before the first character of all lines)

Comment: @Cyryl1972 Fixing it it should be: `:1,$s/^/\t`. If you want to waste the resources for capturing you'd have to do: `1,$s/^\(.\)/\t\1` but this is entirely unnecessary and so pointless.

Comment: I don't like modifying other's answers but you made a typo it seems. You wrote: `/1` ... Add back the preserved text ... but it should be `\1`.

Comment: Of course @Cyryl1972 a further optimisation is using `%` instead of `1,$` of course like `:%s/^/\t/`.