# supertab plugin in vim

Tags: vim, supertab

so my problem just like this thread
[How can I insert a real tab character in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951672/how-can-i-insert-a-real-tab-character-in-vim)

I install supertab plugin and everytime I press tab on my keboard the autocompletion is always shows up.
because I code in python, I will always use real tab, so the solution is to use ctrl+v then tab.
is there any better solution, so that I'm not missing my supertab and I can use my real tab, just like old tab ??

Answer (score 3):

From the `SuperTab` [doc](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/master/doc/supertab.txt):

> So if you don't want supertab to start completion at the start of a line,
>     after a comma, or after a space, you can set g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter
>     to ['^', ',', '\s'].

---

```
" put this into vimrc file
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['^', ',', '\s']
```