# How do I add a character at a specific position in a string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and want to insert a character at a specific position in a string using regular expression replacement.

What would the expressions be to, say, insert a comma at position 6 of every row?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to add a character after the sixth character, simple use the search

```
^(.{6})
```

and the replacement

```
$1,
```

(Example inserts a `,`)

technically spoken this will replace the first 6 characters of every line with MatchGroup 1 (backreference `$1`) followed by a comma.

Comment: Didn't know about using $1.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to insert a number you have to write `($1)0` otherwise it looks for group number "10"