# Notepad++ How do I add a comma at a specific column position?

Tags: mysql, csv, notepad++, ascii

I have pretty large ASCII file (1.7mil rows) that I need to insert commas into at specific column positions.  I am doing this because I am trying to convert the file to csv so I can import it into mysql.  Unless there is a better approach (no doubt), what I am trying to do is insert comma at the specific column positions where I know fields end.  This is not a job for column mode as dragging through 1.7mil rows would be insane.

I have tried this solution - [How do I add a character at a specific postion in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841350/how-do-i-add-a-character-at-a-specific-postion-in-a-string)

but it did not work.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: How many total columns will there be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert after the 4th character on each line:

```
Find:    ^(.{4})
Replace: \1,
```

(Ticking *Regular Expression* in the find/replace dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to import the txt file you have into mysql as a table with a single column. Then split the string using SUBSTRING()

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, 1, 8) AS Column1
  , SUBSTRING(col, 9, 8) AS Column2
  , SUBSTRING(col, 17, 16) AS Column3
FROM table
```

You can modify this query to do `SELECT INTO` or `INSERT INTO`. Depends on how you want to get it to the final table.

I've had to do it this way before because it was a recurring process and needed to be automated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JChao.  Going with Alexs solution but will put yours in my files.