# Replace character in specific position with another character using regular expression, Vim

Tags: regex, vim

Still a regular expressions newb but I'm still learning. What I would like to do is replace the number '1' in bold here using Vim and regular expressions. But the catch is that it has to do it not only for this line, but for every line ON THIS VERY POSITION. So in other words, this '1' happens to be in the 29th space on my flat file. I want to change it to '2'. Can anyone lend me a hand? 
Thank you in advance.

2017033112xxxxxxxxx194205252**1**2007

Comment: [Like this ?](https://regex101.com/r/WSD0YU/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, @Rahul, I don't see your reply.

Comment: @Rahul I can only see "Like this ?"

Comment: Click on it to follow.

Answer (score 3):

```
%s/\%29c[0-9]/2/g
```

It will find any number (from 0 to 9) in the 29th column and replace it with 2.

Comment: Thanks Jose. This is pretty cool as well. Will it work for strings of more than one character?

Comment: If you replace [0-9] regex, with an expression to match more than one character, then this should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
%s/^\(.\{28}\)1/\12/
```

This will preserve the first 28 characters of each line, and replace the '1' in the 29th position with a '2'

Comment: This is great. Thanks Chris! I can see where I where it basically escapes everything up to the 28th character, now.

Answer (score 2):

**Changes `1`'s in the 29th position to `2` using *match start* `\zs`**

```
%s/^.\{28\}\zs1/2
```

**before**

```
123456789012345678901234567890123
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525212007
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525292006
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525212005
```

**after**

```
123456789012345678901234567890123
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525222007
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525292006
2017033112xxxxxxxxx19420525222005
```