# Make sure all indents in a block of text are the same in vim

Tags: vim

I am having the hardest time indenting things consistently in vim, and get no end of `IndentationError` in python. Even setting all these tab-related settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/234578/651174 makes things no better.

How would I do the following in vim to normalize all indentation for a block of text? https://gyazo.com/a333f05e8b4d8034967029005f77ea27

[image]

I've tried doing the `ctrl` `v` visual mode, but can't seem to figure out how to use that for my purpose, or if there's something else I should be doing here. What would be the best way to do the above?

Comment: After selecting with `ctrl v`, hit `I` (uppercase 'I') and insert the desired number of spaces (or tabs), and `Esc` when done. Then, one can use `:set list` to check the result. `:set nolist` turns the setting back off.

Comment: @bert -- thanks, what does `:set (no)list` do?

Comment: `:set list` allows spaces, tabs, eols and other hidden characters to be displayed in an obvious way. For example, tabs are shown as `^I`. Take a look at `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'` for more.

Comment: For future use, take a look at indentLine plugin which will ease your indentation problem :)  https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine.git

Answer (score 0):

use visual mode to select a block of text and hit '=' to indent the code correctly. To effect the whole file use `gg=G`, which translates to go to the beginning of the file and indent correctly to the bottom of the file.
Put the following in your vimrc and use `:ReformatFile` for easy re-indenting.

```
function ReformatFile()
    exec "normal! mqHmw"
    exec "normal! gg=G"
    exec "normal! 'wzt`q"
endfunction
command ReformatFile silent call ReformatFile()
```

`mqHmw` marks your current position and and the top of your current window see `:h marks`

"'wzt`q" moves your cursor to the mark w, moves the line to the top of the file and than to the line and column of mark q

Sry for my bad english, but try to type out the commands in vim and read the docs. The marks q/w are chosen arbitrary.

Comment: @Chlez -- thanks, could you please explain the `mqHmw"` and `'wzt\`q"` commands please?